# When I run this sample pygame code DOS window appears and suddenly disappears without waiting any user input

Tags: animation, pygame, window, screen

When I run this sample PyGame code, a command window appears and suddenly disappears without waiting any user input. What is wrong? I am a newbie and trying to learn python. I have only VBA experiance previously.

The Python version is: Python 3.8.

```
import pygame
import sys
pygame.init() 

win = pygame.display.set_mode((500,500))
pygame.display.set_caption("First Game") 

x = 50
y = 50
width = 40
height = 60
vel = 5 

run = True 

while run:
    pygame.time.delay(100) 

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False 

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        x -= vel 

    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        x += vel 

    if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
        y -= vel 

    if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        y += vel 
    win.fill((0,0,0))  # Fills the screen with black
    pygame.draw.rect(win, (255,0,0), (x, y, width, height))
    pygame.display.update()
    pygame.quit()
    sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 3):

Both your `pygame.quit()` and `sys.exit()` should be *outside* of the `run` loop, so that they execute only when the loop exits.

What you have now will run a *single* iteration, because it exits at the end of that iteration. Some people say a short game is a good game but you *can* take that too far :-)

What I see when I run your code is that the window with the red square appears briefly, then the whole program exits. When I *fix* your indentation, the window stays there and I can move the red square with the arrow keys:

[image]

In other words, this is the form you need:

```
run = True
while run:
    do_stuff()
pygame.quit()
sys.exit() # Probably not needed since you'll exit anyway.
```

It also sounds like you're running it from an IDE, given that the window disappears. I always like to run it from the command line so that, should an exception occur (or important output shows up), I can *see* it after the program has finished.

Comment: As you said sys.exit is not needed. But pygame.quit is outside of the loop. I try both IDE and command line, no chance. :(

Comment: @CzmHrptl: based on the code you posted, neither the quit nor the exit are outside the loop. Their indent level puts them clearly as the final two steps of each iteration.

Comment: Thnx very much. Got it now.